# SQL Server rename column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following query that gathers the column names for a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM theDBNameHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'markers'
```

That works just fine giving me the needed column names of that table. However, I want to rename the column names to something else. I tried the following:

```
SELECT  venueID AS 'Venue ID', 
        venueEventDate AS 'Venue Date', 
        venueCounty AS 'Venue County', 
        venueAdvocate AS 'Venue Advocate', 
        venueSpanish AS 'in Spanish', 
        lastUpdated AS 'Last Updated', 
        updatedBy AS 'Updated By', 
        SysSrcLoadDt AS SysSrcLoadDt 
FROM theDBNameHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'markers'
```

The error it tosses to me is pretty much saying

> Invalid column name 'venueXXXXXXXX'

How would I go about changing the default column name with using the query above? Is this even possible to do in the first place?

Comment: Those columns don't exist in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. They exist in the markers table. If you want to alias your columns when selecting just add the alias in the select statement.

Comment: why would you want spaces in your columnname?

Comment: What do you actually need to do? venueID is the column in your table, not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, right?

Comment: @Aツ its going onto an HTML table and I would like for that row to be nicely formatted from **venueID** to **Venue ID** just for the sake of it reading better to the user.

Comment: `DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME` should do the job, sir!

Comment: Do you need a user-friendly list of (renamed) columns, or do you need a dataset with renamed column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need the `CASE` statement

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'venueID'
             THEN 'Venue ID'
             WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'venueEventDate'
             THEN 'Venue Date'
             WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'venueCounty'
             THEN 'Venue County'
             -- do the rest of columns here
            END AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM theDBNameHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'markers'
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thanks Ala.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only column names:

```
SELECT  venueID        AS [Venue ID], 
        venueEventDate AS [Venue Date], 
        venueCounty    AS [Venue County], 
        venueAdvocate  AS [Venue Advocate], 
        venueSpanish   AS [in Spanish], 
        lastUpdated    AS [Last Updated], 
        updatedBy      AS [Updated By], 
        SysSrcLoadDt   AS [SysSrcLoadDt] 
FROM markers
WHERE 1 = 2  -- column headers only, comment if you want rows also
```

or as `Sean Lange` proposed in comment:

```
SELECT  '' AS [Venue ID], 
        '' AS [Venue Date], 
        '' AS [Venue County], 
        '' AS [Venue Advocate], 
        '' AS [in Spanish], 
        '' AS [Last Updated], 
        '' AS [Updated By], 
        '' AS [SysSrcLoadDt] 
WHERE 1 = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/389110)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

If you wanted names in one column:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('Venue ID'), ('Venue Date'), ('Venue County'),
     ('Venue Advocate'), ('in Spanish'),  ('Last Updated'),
     ('Updated By'), ('SysSrcLoadDt') ) AS t(column_name);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/389136)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╗
║  column_name   ║
╠════════════════╣
║ Venue ID       ║
║ Venue Date     ║
║ Venue County   ║
║ Venue Advocate ║
║ in Spanish     ║
║ Last Updated   ║
║ Updated By     ║
║ SysSrcLoadDt   ║
╚════════════════╝
```

Comment: Or you could just make the select statement a list of strings and not bother with a table at all. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Updated :)

Comment: Use the first part this solution if you want only metadata. Use appropriate WHERE condition, if you want the data with nicely named columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rename column names, use the Alter table and Rename Column keywords...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

Comment: Would that permanently rename the column(s) or just for that current query (on the fly without changes)?

Comment: This will permanently rename the column(s). With embedded space, which you really do not want to do.

Comment: @PhilipKelley I completely agree - however the question specifically asked how to rename column names, hence the answer.